# Sublime Text 2 EOFError

Tags: python-2.7, sublimetext2, eoferror

I'm studying Python using Sublime Text 2.

I typed just the following two statements:

```
usr = raw_input('input any letters: ')
print usr
```

After pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, the following error message occurred.

```
input any letters: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jun/Documents/workspace/studyPython/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    usr = raw_input('input any letters: ')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

How can I fix it? (I'm using Python 2.7.3 in OS X 10.8.2)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `raw_input` isn't getting any input when you run the file in Sublime Text 2, so Python is throwing an error.

In the console that appears (where you see the error), there isn't anywhere for you to type in your arguments. You need to run the script at the command line to make it work. At a shell prompt (in OS X, probably **Terminal**, found in `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`), type the following line:

```
python /path/to/script/test.py
```

The following line then appears:

```
input any letters:
```

with a cursor at the end of the line. This is prompting you to enter your `raw_input`, which allows it to set the `use` variable. You then type some text, for example:

```
input any letters: this is some text
```

and Python will print what you just typed:

```
this is some text
```

This doesn't work in SL2, because SL2 (afaik) doesn't have a way to offer you that prompt for `raw_input`.